# clear all records from data set in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

i am working on vb.net windows form..in my button click i have given code like this:

```
  Dim rpt As New DelivaryPerformance
     Dim ds As New DataSet
       Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
         Dim rpt As New DelParkingtype
        Dim locid As Integer = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", CmbLocations.Text)
        Dim cmdstatus As New SqlCommand("IBS_DelivaryStaus", con.connect)
        cmdstatus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdstatus.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da.SelectCommand = cmdstatus
        da.Fill(ds)
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
```

while i am clicking each time in my button click,,i want to clear all records from my data set,,how i can clear my all records from my dataset

Comment: You already are by usage of the new keyword and the fact that the scope will only be for the button click event anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to clear all rows from the tables contained in a dataset you could use

```
 ds.Clear()
```

MSDN reference
[DataSet.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This however, removes the records, not the tables schema. If you want to get rid of the tables also then you need to use

```
 ds.Tables.Clear()
```

However, in the context of your code, the dataset is created as new, and so it is already empty until you fill it with the appropriate command, so it is not clear in which context you need to empty it.